# Публикация совей библиотеки в GitLab Android

Tags: java, android, git, kotlin, repository

Хочу опубликовать свою библиотеку через gitlab Пробовал делать так

```
  maven {
                url "https://******/api/v4/projects/***/packages/maven"
                credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                    name = "Deploy-Token"
                    value = DEPLOY_TOKEN
                }
                authentication {
                    header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
                }
            }
```

Но это при команде из `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
deployLib:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./gradlew publish
  only:
    - develop
```

Выдавало ошибку

```
Execution failed for task ':auth:publishReleaseAarPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'releaseAar' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not PUT 'https://****/api/v4/projects/***/packages/maven/org/****/***/auth/1.0.0-beta/auth-1.0.0-beta.aar'. Received status code 404 from server: Not Found
```

Нашел на одном источнике что нужно добавить не Deploy-token а Job-Token

```
maven {
                url "${CI_API_V4_URL}/groups/***/packages/maven"
                credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                    name = 'Job-Token'
                    value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
                }
                authentication {
                    header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
                }
            }
```

Теперь код выглядит так, но не могу понять даже из доков где взять `CI_JOB_TOKEN` и `CI_API_V4_URL` подскажите либо словом или ссылкой на годную статью, что не так, не критикуйте слишком, впервые публикую свою либу

Comment: Его брать не надо. `When a pipeline job is about to run, GitLab generates a unique token and injects it as the CI_JOB_TOKEN predefined variable.` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html

Comment: Про переменные GitLab вот тут много интересного: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

Comment: А как насчет CI_API_V4_URL?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#enable-debug-logging

Comment: Хочу еще спросить а в чем разница между уровнями  Maven packages, а именно Project-level, Group-level, Instance-level?

Comment: Все же есть в документации. Это как области видимости. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#use-the-gitlab-endpoint-for-maven-packages

Comment: Извини за вопрос, но я вижу что ты с этим сталкивался, а я топчусь вокруг и без успехов, скажи почему так      maven {
                url "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/266/packages/maven"
                credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                    name = 'Job-Token'
                    value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
                }
                authentication {
                    header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
                }
            }

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133332/discussion-between-svetl9chok-and-eugene-krivenja).